# Error when deploying a smart contract that implements IUniswapV2Router02

Tags: uniswap, bsc

I'm trying to implement a token and list it in pancakeswap. I got the code from babyusdt contract. I'm using truffle tool for compiling and deploying. This is the constructor:

[image]

Actually I changed the IUniswapV2Router constructor with this address: 0xA051966f823DEF0433Ac9eA84B0C5EFBA5011a08. This address is UniSwapV2Router contract deployed on testnet.
The problem I'm having is first when I compile the contract this is shown:

[image]

But everything is fine. When I try to migrate the contract to the bsc testnet I see the following error:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? I have the interface in my project and I just call the implementation like in the picture. Should I use libraries? I tried import uniswap contracts from @uniswap/v2-core/contracts or write the contract in the same file but the error is still occurring. When I remove these lines the error disappears. Please, any help? Thanks

Update: Debugging I saw the error is on the line _uniswapV2Router.factory() but I don't know what happens

Comment: Consider using [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) instead of Truffle. It has stack traces and console.log.

Comment: A pre-fab Hardhat-based template that you could quickly fork to debug your issue: [solidity-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template).

Answer (score 1):

Check the optimize with 200 or 500 runs to avoid the 24k warning